# Do not start X at startup on xUbuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg

How can I change the a xUbuntu 12.04 so X do **not** start at startup?

I tried to remove gdm with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
```

but that did not change much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in 11.10 and later, Xubuntu uses lightdm. You can prevent lightdm from starting by adding "text" to the grub command line in `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

Then update grub:

```
$ sudo update-grub2
```